# What is the difference between char word[25]; and char word[25] = "";?

Tags: c, validation, initialization

I'm trying various code to check Palindrome words, sure there are so many ways to code it, I somehow find something that triggers my curiosity but I couldn't find any answer somewhere although the code run good

That's found that there's a slight differences between two array of char wordReverse declaration below.

Could anyone give an explanation of these two declarations?

```
bool checkPallen(char word[]){
    char wordReverse[25] = ""; //error if used char wordReverse[25];
    int revCount = 0;

    for(int i = strlen(word) - 1; i >= 0; i--){
       wordReverse[revCount] = word[i]; //
       revCount++;
    }

    if(strcmp(wordReverse, word) == 0) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: word[0] is guaranteed to be 0

Comment: so the char word[25]; will result an undefined behaviour?

Comment: You don't ensure that the reversed copy is null terminated explicitly.  When you initialize the array, null termination happens implicitly as long as the input is shorter than the array – so it works.  When you don't initialize the array, you don't have a null terminated string so the comparisons don't work as expected.  Always ensure you null terminate your strings (arguably, they aren't really strings until you do put the null terminator in the right place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that uninitialized local variables have indeterminate values.

When you read from `wordReverse`,

```
strcmp(wordReverse, word)
```

`strcmp` takes two strings, i.e. it expects to find a NUL terminator somewhere.

Your loop that fills `wordReverse` doesn't terminate it, so you get undefined behavior here.

Fix:

```
wordReverse[revCount] = '\0';
```

after the loop.

The version that initializes `wordReverse` as

```
char wordReverse[25] = "";
```

works because it is equivalent to `char wordReverse[25] = { '\0' }`, which sets the first element to `'\0'` explicitly and all remaining elements to `'\0'` implicitly.

---

NB:

```
if (X) return true;
return false;
```

is equivalent to

```
return !!X; // Returns 1 if and only if X is not 0, and 0 otherwise
```